# How to update haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml file for more face detection

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, face-recognition, face-detection

Hello I am using opencv and facenet model along with tensorflow for face detection and recognition.

Now my face recognition working very well. But I have accuracy problem for face detection.

I have huge data which contains faces but not detected by harrcascade.
So I want to add that images into haarcascade for improving the accuracy of face detection.
How could I update this file for detection more face?

Comment: read the paper (viola & jones) and search for tutorials. You'll have to train from scratch. Give Deep Learning a try if you want to maximize accuracy

Comment: If you are flexible with using other face detection models then you can try using the frontal face detector Caffe model of OpenCV's DNN module. It provides much better accuracy than Haar. You can refer here if you want to know more about it: https://towardsdatascience.com/face-detection-models-which-to-use-and-why-d263e82c302c?source=friends_link&sk=c9e2807cf216115d7bb5a9b827bb26f8

Comment: Okay - looks good

Answer (score 0):

Modern face recognition pipelines consists of 4 common stages: detect, align, represent and verify. Just detecting faces is not enough. Based on the google research, alignment increases accuracy more than 1%.

I recommend you to use deepface because it handles those stages in the background.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
obj = DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", model_name = "Facenet")
print(obj)
```

Verify function includes detect and align tasks.

You can verify multiple faces as well.

```
obj = DeepFace.verify([
      ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg"], 
      ["img1.jpg", "img3.jpg"]
   ], 
   model_name = "Facenet"
)
```

Those are face verification and you can apply face recognition. I mean that you can find a face in a large database.

```
df = DeepFace.find(img_path = "img1.jpg", db_path = "C:/my_db", model_name = "Facenet")
```

You can test deepface package for different face recognition models. VGG-Face, Facenet, OpenFace, DeepFace and DeepID are wrapped models in the package. VGG-Face and Facenet are the most robust ones based on my experiments.

Comment: I have used deepface for the recognition and deepface uses opencv harrcascade for face detection

Comment: yes, but additionally it applies face alignment which is not served in opencv as out-of-the-box function.

Answer (score 0):

the default face detection module in deepface is opencv but it wraps ssd, dlib and mtcnn as well.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
backends = ['opencv', 'ssd', 'dlib', 'mtcnn']
detected_face = DeepFace.detectFace("img.jpg", detector_backend = backends[0])
```

You can run face recognition with those different face detectors as well. Face detection is more successful in ssd than opencv haar cascade. But they both uses opencv's eye detection to align faces. Resolution of dlib's alignment function is low. That's why, the best results come from mtcnn.

```
from deepface import DeepFace
DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", detector_backend = 'mtcnn')
```